# How to properly create once-a-day Azure Log Alert for pod errors?

Tags: azure, alert, kql, azure-alerts

I created an Azure Alert using a Query (KQL - Kusto Query Language) reading from the Log. That is, it's an Log Alert.

After a few minutes, the alert was triggered (as I expected based on my condition).
My condition checks if there are Pods of a specific name in Failed state:

```
KubePodInventory
| where TimeGenerated between (now(-24h) .. now())
| where ClusterName == 'mycluster'
| where Namespace == 'mynamespace'
| where Name startswith "myjobname"
| where PodStatus == 'Failed'
| where ContainerStatusReason == 'Completed' //or 'Error' or doesn't matter? (there are duplicated entries, one with Completed and one with Error)
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

These errors stay in the log, and I only want to catch (alert about them) once per day (that is, I check if there is at least one entry in the log (threshold), then fire the alert).

Is the log query evaluated every time there is a new entry in the log, or is it evaluated in a set frequency?I could not find in Azure Portal a frequency specified to check Alerts, so maybe it evaluates the Alert(s) condition(s) every time there is something new in the Log?

Comment: As per my understanding Scheduling an alert through KQL is not possible. You can use any scheduling App/tool like Power Automate to get KQL run when required and trigger alert as per condition defined.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor Log Alerts are evaluated based on the frequency you specify when you create the alert rule. By default, the frequency is set to evaluate the alert rule every 5 minutes. However, you can change this frequency to a value between 1 min and 1 day.

[image]

When you create a log alert rule, you specify a query that is used to evaluate the alert condition. The query is evaluated at the frequency you specify, and if the query returns any results, the alert is triggered.

In your case, you have specified a query that checks for Pods of a specific name in Failed state. If the query returns any results, the alert will be triggered. Since you only want to receive the alert once per day, you can set the frequency of the alert rule to `1 day`. This will ensure that the query is evaluated once per day, and if there are any Pods of the specific name in Failed state, you will receive the alert.

For more info please refer to this doc: [Configure alert logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/tutorial-log-alert#configure-alert-logic)

Comment: Thank you. My issue now is related to the time. If I set 1 day, it runs every day at the time the alert was created, and I can't set, for example, to run it every day at 8 am.